# UART line causes exess current consumption

Tags: pcb, stm32, uart, power-consumption

I'm currently working on a project that involves an STM32WB55 microcontroller, a GPS module, and a LoRa module. I have encountered an issue where, when I put all these devices into sleep mode, I observe an unexpected current consumption of about 7mA, which is excessively high for my application's needs.

The UART line is connected between the mcu and the LoRa module and also to a header that i added on the PCB to monitor the communication between the two modules.Interestingly, when I connect the UART line to my PC throught the UART header, the measured current supplied by the battery drops significantly to 40µA, which is the expected consumption in sleep mode. however when i measured the current passing through the UART line from the PC to my UART header on the pcb i found it to be a approximately 7mA, indicating that the pcb is drawing that undesired previous current from the pc using the UART line and does not pass throught multimeter, which is why the current supplied by the battery is reduced.

I've tried altering the UART's configuration in STM32CubeIDE to different states - pull-up, pull-down, and neither - but the issue persists. I've also checked for potential short circuits between the UART line and both the power and ground pins, but found no evidence of shorts.

Additional observations include:

- When I disconnect the Vcc from the microcontroller, the current drops to around 3mA.
- When I turn off the GPS module, there's no change in current consumption.

For this design, I've relied on the MCU's internal pull-up resistors, not adding any external ones.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on potential solutions or additional tests I should perform to diagnose this issue. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Please post schematics. Also can you somehow edit the problem to be more clear, at first you say the consumption goes lower when PC is connected, but then you say the current leaks to PC from UART, but then it was the UART of LoRa module, so seriously, make sure what you write makes sense when read. Which UART modules, LoRa modules, GPS modules you use, and what IO voltages they use, and what's the MCU IO voltage?

Comment: hi, thanks for the remark. I have just edited the paragraph that explains the UART connexion. I am using the Nemeus mm002 as a LoRa module and the L86M33 as a gps module. unfortunately i can't post the schematic as i didn't design it and it's confidential to the company. also by IO voltages do you mean for the UART tx and rx ?

Comment: If you can't post the schematics, then we can't have a look if it is incorrectly designed and in which way. And yes IO voltages of UART or everything that's connected together. For example, if the PC UART module runs at 5V, it may not be possible to connect it to a 3.3V MCU, unless the MCU pin is specifically said to tolerate 5V, and it may only tolerate 5V when powered, but may damage if 5V is on pin when unpowered.

Comment: for the mcu, icfound on this on the datasheet that VIH min is 0.7 x VDD  but it does not specify the maximum. and the only info i found in the nemeus datasheet is this : Supply: -Minimum voltage= 2.7V -Recommended voltage=3V -Maximum voltage= 3.3V. ad i am powering all of them using 3v3. So you are saying that connecting their UART line to that of the pc of 5v might have damaged the UART lines ?

Comment: The MCU atasheet does say the maximum but it depends on the pin type and different pins have different types and you don't say which pin you use. But the pin types and their limits are in the datasheet.

Comment: Sorry for the Delay i was having lunch. So i just checked the pin and ball definitions table and it does say that pins PA2 and PA3 are 5v tolerant ( the ones i am using for LPUART.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described, the issue would appear to be that the LoRa module is drawing current through the UART line while in sleep mode.

Remove the LoRa module UART lines to confirm.

Check that you are actually putting it into 'official' sleep mode (simply removing Vcc from the module will likely result in what you are seeing because the module will be powered through protection diodes on the input).

Comment: But is it possible for the modules to sink such a high current from the UART lines ?

Comment: Yes it is, if the Vcc is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In low current application, everything is in the details. When you say that your input current is around 7mA when operating, it means that their something is sinking current. Then you plug your computer and he supplies the current and not the input of your circuit. That is really not surprising! Essentially, you are bypassing your entry.

When measuring micro amps, you need to be careful on your instrumentation. Most dmm aren't really able to measure those accurately due to burden voltage (if your power isn't the right voltage, your current won't be the same (assuming SMPS) or other issues. Can you detail a bit more how you are measuring that current? Are you able to see the current waveform? Is it constant, is their burst, so on.

You said that you enabled the internal pull up resistor. Maybe ST don't have the push pull mode, but UART should be in push pull. Not state the obvious but TX should be an output and RX an input (RX should not have any pullups in either scenario).

If you think the UART is what draws the current, have you tried to break them (by changing the pin assignment for instance)? I doubt that you will see that much difference.

Finally, how did you evaluate the current consumption? It is tricky to do a good evaluation and that might bring you to false conclusion.

And yes, please share some schematics!

Comment: STM32s so have a push pull mode, and obviously you can't leave an unconnected RX input pin floating, so the pull-up must be enabled. However that does not apply if pin is 5V toletant and you feed in 5V so pull-up must be external. And the schematics can't be shared as said. Most of the questions here should maybe be comments instead of requesting more info in an answer.

Comment: First, it was too long for a comment. Sharing the full schematic might be prohibited, but some parts of it could help. For instance a block diagram or other. I'm not really asking to get the info but suggesting him to consider those aspects.

I agree you can't leave an unconnected input pin, but with the info we got, I think the Lora module is always there.  I also think that his issue is there with or without the PC connected.  UART isn't even a bus, so I don't understand why he's plugging 3 devices.